# Переход с консольных приложений на оконные

Tags: c++, winapi

Хотелось бы перейти из консольных приложений на оконные, но сколько ни смотрю на эти api функции, у меня одни квадратные глаза. Я вообще не могу втянуть, что делать с этой функцией, куда ее вписать, хотя когда писал для консоли, с функциями проблем не было. Может поможете, кто чем может: сайтом, справочником, или так можно объяснить... В общем спасибо сразу. )

Answer (score 8):

Попробуйте Qt, это не winapi, возможно вам подойдет

Answer (score 6):

Смотря на какие окошки Вам хочется перейти. Если именно под Windows, то можно посмотреть WinForms. И вообще под окошки лучше писать на C# или Java. На чистом winApi сложновато. Я пробовал... мне не очень понравилось. Есть конечно MFC обёртка для winApi, но это вообще прошлый век, лучше даже туда и не соваться.

Если на C++ если кроссплатформенные фреймворки: посмотрите на Qt, wxWidget (я как раз сейчас немного изучаю этот фреймворк), GTK+.

Comment: Может хватит уже советовать WinForms?:) Есть же WPF, который пропагандирует намного более "правильный" подход к построению гуя. WinForms же фактически является оберткой над WinAPI

Comment: WinForms просто значительно проще WPF. Для обучения пойдет. Хотя лучше сразу учиться правильным вещам.

Comment: WinForms значительно хуже WPF в том, что (1) на нём тяжело писать приложения с нормальной архитектурой, (2) в нём много специфических для WinAPI-программирования деталей, учить которые нормальному программисту нафиг не упало, особенно в свете уже пришедшего к нам WinRT. Лучше начинать сразу с концептуально чистого WPF.

Comment: Или сразу смотреть в сторону WinRT, несмотря на всё то, чем его поливают, API довольно чист и красив, нет тяжелого наследия и костылей обратной совместимости, как в WPF или WinAPI

Answer (score 3):

Недавно наткнулся на эту страничку, все описано довольно доступным языком:
[Основы программирования для Win32 API](http://dims.karelia.ru/win32/)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте библиотеки: Qt или GTK+

WinAPI это конечно мощный и быстрый инструмент, но не кроссплатформенный, да и скорость разработки на нем оставляет желать лучшего.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь о **WinAPI**, то по своему опыту, могу сказать - функции и правда по началу кажутся очень страшнми, но все начинается, как ни странно с классов и велосипедов, о которых ни кто не говорит, ибо стесняются, но все поголовно пишут. ))

И по-моему, тут нет ничего удивительного - в WinAPI есть сразу много чего, а для решения основных задач достаточно только некоторой доли от этого всего, поэтому можно увидеть как в нескольких различных классах-обертках используются одни и те же API-функции.

Некоторые пишут подсматривая в готовые фреймворки, типа MFC, WTL, я подсматривал тогда в Delphi.

Для облегчения жизни, советую брать курс на интегрированную работу с каким-нибудь готовым набором примитивов, типа STL **и в обязательном порядке научиться работать в MSDN**

- очень не помещает локальная копия MSDN, ну прямо очень-очень не помешает, да-да, именно в ней по началу приходится проводить основное время.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте [тут](http://www.gamesmaker.ru/32-vvedenie_v_winapi_chast_vtoraya/) о самом принципе использования WinAPI в C++

Answer (score 1):

[Создание приложения Win32 (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384843(v=VS.100).aspx)

> В этом пошаговом руководстве демонстрируется создание основного приложения на базе Win32, который отображается в окне "Hello, World!". Можно использовать код, при разработке как шаблон для создания других приложений на основе Win32 в данном пошаговом руководстве.

Answer (score 1):

Основы винапи выучить можно за несколько дней, а вот дальше придется напрячся, я сам винапи изучал и учу до сих пор.Уроки посмотри в интернете. [Пишем на WinAPI с «нуля»](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/api32.xml) - вот например.

Answer (score 1):

По многочисленным советам, использую книгу "Программирование для Windows 95 Петзолд Ч.". Очень доступно все расписано и дает хоть какие-то основы, а дальше уже легче будет и не нужно смотреть на то, что это для windows 95, потому как по тем же советам говорится о незначительных изменениях в winapi и почти никаких относительно этой книги. Если ошибаюсь, то поправьте.

Answer (score 0):

Советую начать с WinAPI, поможет вам в этом Юрий Щупак и его [книга](http://hardfire.ru/book/Shupak_Win32_API) "Win32 Api. Эффективная разработка приложений" - отличная книга в плане учебника и в плане справочника. Ее можно и нужно читать всем новичкам в разработке оконных приложений, там прекрасно и самое главное **доступно** описаны основные концепции Windows. Зуб даю, что после изучения этой книги сможете написать оконное приложение с практически любым функционалом, чего не скажешь о его внешней красоте:)
Кстати, чтобы вас не пугали типы в WinAPI посмотрите [венгерскую нотацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).